# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a 2D game and me need the object to turn towards the player. `Player` is where the object will turn

```
public Transform Player;
public Transform Turell;
Rigidbody TurelPhisics;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var turn = Quaternion.Lerp(Turell.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, Player.position - Turell.position), Time.deltaTime * 1.8f);

    TurelPhisics.MoveRotation(turn.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is too short. Try to expand and show how the variables get their values. This is hard to understand as variables are not defined.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Please, explain:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) expects a `Quaternion`. You are passing in a `float` in

```
TurelPhisics.MoveRotation(turn.eulerAngles.z);
```

---

The one that would take a `float` rather would be a [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) where [`Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html) takes a float since there is only rotation in the Z-Axis.

So  since you stated

> I make a 2D game

just change the type to

```
Rigidbody2D TurelPhisics;
```